# can datetime plotted using data from a sqlite database in python & matplotlib without using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am new to programming:(. I have an sqlite database.I insert as well as query data from the same. It has two columns, datetime(type text) and a 0 or 1(integer). I want to fetch this data using python and plot graph in matplotlib.

I tried it, but it seems that the date time format and its conversion is creating problem for me. I dont want to use pandas, but failed to get a function in matplotlib though.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime,date

#define datetimes
strt_timestamp=1234567878
end_timestamp=1234568980

#create and connect database and tables
conn=sqlite3.connect('table1.db')
cur=conn.cursor()
#cur.execute('CREATE TABLE machine1(dt_tim TEXT,workingcnd INT)')
conn=sqlite3.connect('table1.db')
cur.execute('DELETE FROM machine1')

#code to create table1 database
while strt_timestamp<=(end_timestamp-54):
        strt_timestamp+=55
        b=datetime.fromtimestamp(strt_timestamp)
        a=b.strftime("%m/%d/%Y,%H:%M:%S");
        c=strt_timestamp%2

        cur.execute('INSERT INTO machine1(dt_tim,workingcnd)VALUES(?,?)', 
(a,c));

cur.execute('SELECT dt_tim,workingcnd FROM machine1');
result=cur.fetchall()
print(result)

cur.execute('SELECT dt_tim FROM machine1')
dt_tim=cur.fetchall()
cur.execute('SELECT workingcnd FROM machine1')
cnd=cur.fetchall()

plt.plot_date(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: There is no need to use pandas. Apart, I may not understand the question, what is `x` in the code?

Comment: Oh..I am so sorry....the plot functions should be as....'plt.plot_date(dt_tim,cnd)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be two problems. First the results from `cur.execute('SELECT dt_tim FROM machine1')` is a list of tuples. You would need to unpack it to get a list of the actual values.
Second, you will need to convert your date strings to `datetime` to be able to plot them with matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime
#define datetimes
strt_timestamp=1234567878
end_timestamp=1234568980

#create and connect database and tables
conn=sqlite3.connect('table1.db')
cur=conn.cursor()
#cur.execute('CREATE TABLE machine1(dt_tim TEXT,workingcnd INT)')
conn=sqlite3.connect('table1.db')
#cur.execute('DELETE FROM machine1')

#code to create table1 database
while strt_timestamp<=(end_timestamp-54):
        strt_timestamp+=55
        b=datetime.fromtimestamp(strt_timestamp)
        a=b.strftime("%m/%d/%Y,%H:%M:%S");
        c=strt_timestamp%2

        cur.execute('INSERT INTO machine1(dt_tim,workingcnd)VALUES(?,?)', 
                    (a,c));

cur.execute('SELECT dt_tim FROM machine1')
dt_tim=[datetime.strptime(d, "%m/%d/%Y,%H:%M:%S") for d, in cur.fetchall()]
cur.execute('SELECT workingcnd FROM machine1')
cnd=[int(d) for d, in cur.fetchall()]
conn.close()

print(dt_tim)
print(cnd)

plt.plot(dt_tim,cnd)
plt.show()
```

Comment: very much thanks @importanceofbeingernest, made me know a lot of things. Mostly problem has been resolved. will scratch my head first if anything more interrupts, and incase even then it doent work, will come back. Thanks all the ways..:)...schönes wockhenende....